# GHC do not resolve correctly constraint in typeclass methods (ghc bug / limitation ?)

Tags: haskell, ghc, typeclass, inference, unification

GHC do not resolve / propagate constraint in the default implementation of some of my class members. The behaviour is really strange and it seems to me like it's a bug.

Can someone help me / explain to me what's wrong ?

1. How can I tell GHC to unify the `a` from the class declaration and the `a` from the class method so the definition is not ambiguous
2. Is there something I don't understand ?

code:

```
module Foo where
import Data.Proxy

data Stuff a = Stuff
  {content :: String}

class HasStuff a where
  stuff :: Stuff a

  -- This works
  useStuffOK :: Proxy a -> (Stuff a)
  useStuffOK _ = (stuff)

  -- those don't work, 
  -- (but I think ghc has all the information necessary to figure it out)
  useStuffBAD :: Proxy a -> (Stuff a, String)
  useStuffBAD _ = (stuff, content (stuff :: Stuff a))
  -- Could not deduce (HasStuff a1) arising from a use of ‘stuff’
  -- from the context (HasStuff a)
  --   bound by the class declaration for ‘HasStuff’
  --   at Test.hs:(7,1)-(17,45)

  useStuffBAD2 :: Proxy a -> String
  useStuffBAD2 _ = content (stuff :: Stuff a)
  -- Could not deduce (HasStuff a1) arising from a use of ‘stuff’
  -- from the context (HasStuff a)
  --   bound by the class declaration for ‘HasStuff’
  --   at Test.hs:(7,1)-(17,45)

instance HasStuff Int where
  stuff = Stuff "ok"

-- inference works here
x :: Stuff Int
x = stuff

-- works here too
x :: String
x = content (stuff :: Stuff Int)
```

Thank you

Comment: It isn't a bug. `useStuffBAD _ = let x = stuff in (x, content x)` and `useStuffBAD2 = content . useStuffOK`. The type really is ambiguous there - you could be referring to any `stuff` in either of those expressions. `useStuffOK` works because the output type is given by the type signature. Since `content :: Stuff a -> String` does not mention the type `a` in the result, uses of this function are ambiguous if the type is not explicitly given or cannot be inferred from the context.

Comment: @user2407038 just edited my question: when I give the type explicitely, it doesn't work neither because ghc doesn't unify the `a` from the class declaration and the `a` from the class method. In my case, useStuffBAD is explicit about what instance it should choose. I still have the impression that this is a problem in ghc.

Comment: I think you maybe need `{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}` on top of your file for that to work - on its own ghc does not know that `Stuff a` from `(Stuff a, String)` is the same as `stuff :: Stuff a`

Comment: @Ravion the code in your update [compiles](https://ideone.com/Wahdck) (at least on 7.10.3) with nothing but `ScopedTypeVariables`, so you either haven't actually enabled, or you are using an older version which may actually have a bug.

Comment: @user2407038 you are right, my bad !

Comment: @epsilonhalbe thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @epsilonhalbe and @user2407038 pointed out, I was missing ScopedTypeVariables extension